# Determine area enclosed by multiple segments

Tags: postgis, polygon, postgresql, line, area

I am trying to determine the area enclosed by multiple linestrings. For example, in the following picture, I have 4 linestrings, forming 2 closed polygons. I'd like to be able to get the coordinates of the polygons. I don't really care what tool I use. For now, I have looked into python-shapely and  postgis and haven't found the correct algorithm for that.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.polygonize.html ?

Comment: Yes, I have. It gives the polygon contains in a closed multi line string. But in my case, they are not necessarily closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for PostgreSQL/PostGIS.

Input geodata table named "linetoarea" shown in Figure 1 below.

[image]

Figure 1

Run Geo-SQL script:

```
WITH 
noded AS (SELECT ST_Node(ST_Union(geom)) geom FROM linetoarea),
polygons AS (SELECT ST_Union(geom) geom FROM (SELECT ST_Polygonize(geom) geom FROM noded) foo)
SELECT ST_Area(geom) area, geom FROM (SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom FROM polygons) boo
```

See the result of the Geo-SQL script execution in Figure 2 below.

[image]

Figure 2

Figure 3 the overlay of the two tables.

[image]

Figure 3

**P.S.**

Our custom Geo-spatial function is called "ST_LinesToPolygons".

Create a Geo-spatial function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_Linestopolygons(
    geom GEOMETRY)
RETURNS TABLE (geom GEOMETRY) AS 
$BODY$  
WITH 
noded AS (SELECT ST_Node(ST_Union(geom)) geom),
polygons AS (SELECT ST_Union(geom) geom FROM (SELECT ST_Polygonize(geom) geom FROM noded) foo)
SELECT geom FROM (SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom FROM polygons) foo;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL
```

Run:

```
SELECT ST_Linestopolygons(ST_Union(geom)) geom FROM <name_line_table>
```

***(-: FOGS :-)***...

Comment: Thank you so much. This is working!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you and others...and look forward to more interesting questions....